# Is it possible to select more than 1 components text in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, forms, combobox, textbox

I was wondering if it would be possible to select multiple components (ie: Textboxes and ComboBoxes) during runtime, to collect or set all thier text values?

Almost like dragging a selection box across them.
To give you an idea of how many I'm talking about, my form currently has around 120 textboxes and 24 comboboxes. So instead of having the user, for example, copy and paste into each box at a time. Could they just drag a box to select them all and paste in one go.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading following: [Implementing Drag and Drop in Visual Basic .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289508(v=vs.71).aspx)